# output waveform of CD4017

Tags: oscilloscope, 555, cd4017

We are trying to create a chaser circuit using a CD4017 counter with the output of a 555 timer as the CD4017's input. The schematic diagram used is here (photo taken from circuit digest):

[image]

When probing the outputs, we get this waveform

[image: output waveform]

Can someone explain why or what causes the /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ portion on the output waveform?

[edit]

Probing the output of 555 and the capacitor produces these waveforms:
[image: output waveform of 555 and capacitor]

Unfortunately, we weren't able to include both the output waveforms (that of the 555 and CD4017) at the same time on a single display. (lol :( ) Also, we forgot to set the traces on the same volts/div and sec/div

Comment: Hard to say without more info. But it appears to occur around the time of each clock from the 555. Can you now add the 555 output to your scope picture? (I'm wondering about proper bypass caps on your ICs and if all this is wired on a protoboard. Plus, I'm curious about the power supply you are using, as well.)

Comment: hi! thanks for the response. sorry, i do not have a picture with both of the outputs from 555  and 4017 put together on the same panel. Also, everything is wired on a breadboard and we are using a constant DC voltage supply (~9V)

Comment: What's a "chaser circuit"?  If you just have a oscillator driving a counter, then you should get a sequence of square waves, each half the frequency of the previous.  Which output produced the top waveform?  How does the time scale relate to the oscillator period?  What voltages?

Comment: I see no chip power decoupling capacitors.

Comment: @OlinLathrop The 4017 is a decade counter with ten outputs that go HI in sequence from a source of pulses is connected to the CLOCK input. The outputs are one at a time, so they "chase."

Comment: @Andyaka Yeah. That, plus the idea of a protoboard, is what first worried me.

Comment: The portions in question appear to be mains frequency and sinusoidal. Are you sure the circuit is exactly as you've presented and that your scope is not doing something strange (no math function enabled and your reference point actually is ground). This could be explained by something like a transistor going open but there is nothing in the supplied schematic that would explain it.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany we've reconstructed the whole of it, and we are getting the same traces (no math enabled). if there is really nothing in the circuit that explains it, i shall consider replacing the ICs(?).  btw, thanks for the insight :)

Comment: Is the 4017 chip _EN pin well connected or is it able to float about?  Are the 4017 chip ground and power well connected and have a decoupling capacito?

Answer (score 1):

My guess, and I cheerfully admit it is a guess, is that you have a bad or missing connection to the Vdd power supply pin on the CD4017.

Power then would being supplied via the 555 through the input protection network on the CD4017.

That could account for the apparently floating outputs when the 555 output goes low.